# Is there a dotnet or msbuild CLI command to start roslyn source code generators without a build?

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

I need a command to only produce the source code with the roslyn source generator without starting a whole build.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `dotnet msbuild -t:compile` or `msbuild -t:compile`.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Sorry for my late answer - thanks thats it! You can write it as an answer and I will tick it as solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no command to do this.

Comment: @PauloMorgado 's comment solved it!